# Blender / AO is bigger than my mesh

Tags: ambient-occlusion

I'm working on a project to combine real-life picture with 3d meshes. As I'm going through compositing, I found this situation where the AO is actually bigger than the real mesh. This causes the hand to have a weird boundary. Even though my actual mesh isn't that big.

Is there a reason why my AO is bigger than my mesh? Can I limit my AO to the mesh size?

As you can see on the 2nd screenshot, real mesh is the exact same size as the picture

[image: boundary so irritating]

[image: As you can see the real mesh is the exact same size as the picture]

Comment: are you sure your original image and rendered image have the exact same ratio?

Comment: I only used a single picture for the background of the camera, so there are no multiple pictures. I'm using only 1 picture

Comment: From the screenshot, it does not look like the images have the same aspect ratio

Comment: @sushibrother you use only one picture as background but you are rendering a new picture. I suspect that the aspect ratio of the background image is not the same as the rendered image and that would explain why they don't overlap correctly.